# How to work with Patch method in Webclient?

Tags: spring-boot, webclient, resttemplate

I have been searching a example for patch method in `Webclient`. I have a four fields in my Model class, I need to update one field (i.e status field), Hence I have decided to use Patch method. But I don't any examples in internet.

I have a piece of code in `RestTemplate`, here I need it in `Webclient`, as I'm migrating to `Webclient`. How to achieve below code?

```
public void updateProfile(UpdateProfile profile, String uniqueId) {
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "merge-patch+json");
        headers.setContentType(mediaType);

        HttpEntity<UpdateProfile> entity = new HttpEntity<>(profile, headers);
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        restTemplate.exchange(firebaseUrl+"/"+path+"/" + uniqueId + ".json", 
                HttpMethod.PATCH, entity, Void.class);
        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following patch method sample from the web client, i have not tested but i hope so you can use the similar approach.

```
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(firebaseUrl);
        webClient.patch()
                 .uri("+path+" + uniqueId + ".json")
                 .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/json-patch+json"))
                 .bodyValue(data)
                 .exchange();
```

remember to add the below artifact in your pom.xml,

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This updates all the 4 fields. Not only the status field. Remaining fields gets update as null.

Comment: It's used ```PATCH``` and maybe you need to invoke additional method.